# In this case would it be better to store data in a database such as SQLite, or in a flat text file?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, text-files, cartesian-product

I'm constructing a small C++ project that will utilize static data (it wont be changed on the user-end, only updated when changed are required). The data itself will consist of five different categories of *items* with various *fields*. An example of these items would be:

```
item1 {a=3, b=2, d=4}
item2 {c=4, d=2, m=3}
...
```

Each item can contain any number of fields (a-z for this example) with an associated value. Each category will have a list of the items (think five different files containing lines of text like above).

The goal of the program will be to find one item from each of these categories, where the different fields they contain will sum to meet the required input (i.e. sum(d) == 10, sum(x) == 20). The resulting five items will meet at least these requirements. I aim at accomplishing this by finding the cartesian-product of the five different categories (after narrowing it down by finding only the items that contain at least one field from the input), and then cycling through the results to find the sets of five items that are correct.

Now on to my question: I'm curious as to whether it would be better to store the data in a text file (and load it on every start), or use SQLite. Using text files would certainly be better to implement, at least to me. But I'm sure it wont be as efficient to load everything, and store it into the proper data objects every time the program is started.

With SQLite, I would have everything at my disposal pretty much immediately, and would be able to perform most of my tasks directly with queries. I am a little iffy on how I would narrow down the tables before finding the cartesian-product, and then further cycle through the results for the answers. I'm sure I could figure that out with time and research, though.

So, experts of StackOverflow, what is your input on this? If it wasn't for the specific operations I'm planning on conducting on the data, I would pick SQLite. But with this, I'm a little unsure, and want to make sure to maintain the simplicity of this for the long run.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use a text file with a standard serialisation format, like XML or JSON. Use a database if you need concurrent read and writes, which you don't appear to.

Comment: If the amount of data is reasonable (which can fit in your ram with no risks) I would go for text and JSON (as Batsheba suggested) nowadays you have plenty of predefined data structures and collections to manipulate data.

Comment: Maybe a NoSQL solution? Your data model made me think about MongoDB ...

Answer (score 1):

This is partially dictated by how many records you're planning on storing - at a certain size the benefits of a RDBMS start to show themselves over having a giant flat file choking out your RAM.

The rules you're talking about are really simple for querying, and you'll have benefits of reliability, data integrity checking and other advantages that RDBMS's bring.  If it were me, I'd go SQLite all day.

Comment: That definitely adds to make the decision more difficult for me. Though, I really don't imagine each category having any more than 500 entries. Would that constitute being small?

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLite would make the database scalabale,being query based it would be faster to do manipulations specially if any new operation needs to be implemented. 
File System management based on delimiters would be much easier to implement as it won't require understanding of query language.
SQLite is someone else's code while FMS would be 'YOUR' code so any bugs or issues faced would be easy to diagnose and fix.

P.S: I am currently working on a EMV payment system(SDK) and had to maintain records of transactions,I initially used SQLite3 for this purpose but later moved my implementation to FMS because there were intermittent issues with the db and it was hard to debug them,the most commom one is an error code 21 in SQLite3 for which least help is available,secondly it is hard to find memory leaks,which a newbie creates easily.
In a nutshell,if your database is not very large,easy to manage and you can design a structure based on delimeters,i would suggest you to go with FMS but ensure you make it 'WELL STRUCTURED'.